# To prove that $f$ ( the complex conjugation map )is orientation reversing when considered as a map from $S^1\to S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, orientation

Considering $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ I need to show that the complex conjugation map is orientation reversing. Thinking $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R^2}$ the conjugation map gives $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$ so it will be orientation reversing by calculating the Jacobian but how to claim it for $S^1$ that I am unable to do. Any hints or help is very much needed.

Comment: Hint: The question asks you to think of the action on the circle. So start with your definition of an orientation of a circle. Then think about the effect of the conjugation map on that orientation.

Comment: Just confirming whether it's the direction you wanted to say? Like I would take a standard orientation form on $S^1$ say $\omega$ and then calculate $f^*(\omega)$ where f is the conjugation map. Then calculate the jacobian ? Is it what you mentioned ?

Comment: You just calculate $f^*\omega$. Then, since $\omega$ is an orientation form on $S^1$, we can write $f^*(\omega)= \phi\cdot \omega$ for some smooth function $\phi:S^1\to\Bbb{R}$. In fact, $\phi$ has to be nowhere vanishing if $f$ is a diffeomorphism, and hence by the intermediate value theorem, $\phi>0$ or $\phi<0$ everywhere. In the first case, the map is said to be orientation-preserving, while in the latter, it is reversing. Which situation occurs for complex conjugation?

Comment: No more Jacobian calculations are necessary; everything has been encoded into the definition of differential forms, wedge products and pullback.

Comment: Ok yes yes missing this crucial thing. Got it